# What happens if one side loses control of all locations in Planetside 2?

Tags: planetside-2

What would happen in Planetside 2 if one of the three forces were to be completely 100% invaded and all of their territories taken over?

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible to completely defeat a faction, because every faction controls one of the three warp gates at the corners of the continent. The warp gates are protected by shields which are completely impenetrable for the other factions, so they can't capture them. Even when a faction got driven back to just their warp gate they can regroup and start a new offensive.

However, a faction can defeat both enemy factions simultaneously by controlling enough territory to "lock" the continent. The continent is then no longer available for a few hours.

Answer (score 0):

Now it has been a while, but last time I played Planet Side 2, taking over 100% of the map was impossible. I recall there was supposed to be new maps that you could take over 100%, but that would only temporarily lock the other factions out before somehow letting them back in. There was however, a main map with a main territory that could not be captured or even invaded. This was to guarantee your faction had at least one territory.